# ElasticSearch - Unable to create mapping using Nest Client

Tags: c#, indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

I am using the [NEST client](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net) for Elastic Search to create a mapping for one one of my indices. I have this method which is supposed to create a mapping on the index "business" but no matter what I do to change it the mapping is not being created!

```
public void CreateIndexWithMappings()
    {
        var mapping= client.CreateIndex("business", index => index
        .AddMapping<BusinessSearchDto>(m => m
        .Properties(props => props
        .Completion (c => c
                .Name(x => x.Name.Suffix("completion"))
                .IndexAnalyzer("analyzer_startswith")
                .SearchAnalyzer("analyzer_startswith")
                .MaxInputLength(30)
                .Payloads(true)
                .PreservePositionIncrements()
                .PreserveSeparators()
        )
        )));
    }
```

After creating the above mapping I am indexing businesses to the newly created "business" index.

```
var indexMany = client.IndexMany<BusinessSearchDto>(businessDtos, "business");
```

When I do `curl -XGET http://localhost/business/businesssearchdto/_mapping` to inspect my mapping I see that the mapping is not created.

I have looked the NEST client examples, many other questions on SO and am out of ideas. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the mapping you wanna create??

Comment: @BlackPOP, it really doesn't matter. If you can give me an example of creating **ANY** mapping using the NEST client's new fluent interface that should be fine because none of the mappings I have tried creating work. Specifically, I am trying to create a mapping on `http://localhost:9200/business/businesssearchdto`